# Why does Google 2FA not display the correct location when behind proxy?

Tags: network, google, account-security

I'm on my corporate proxy and using Google 2-factor authentication to log into my machine.  When I get the notification on my phone, it says that I'm trying to connect from Moscow, Russia, even though I'm in the United States.  In the past, this has not been a problem. It only started occurring a few weeks ago. As such, I'm worried about a Man-in-the-Middle attack.

Is it normal for Google to display incorrect 2-factor login locations when behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into a similar issue with one of my personal VPSs.

When I browse through a SOCKS5 Proxy through my vps in LA my google home page thinks I am in Hong Kong.

After some googling, I figured out that its most likely just a error in someones [GeoIP Database](https://lite.ip2location.com/).

I would check https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip against the ones listed in the 2fa logs ... but its most likely a non-issue